# Magento 2 custom module override knockout template

Tags: knockoutjs, requirejs, magento2.1.6, knockout

How can we override a knockout template in a custom module?
I know how we can do this in our own theme but I need this in a module.

For example I like to override this file:
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/form.html`

Is this possible?

Comment: An idea: create a mixin on the component and set the template from within the mixin/component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can override a knockout template in a custom module, just did it, in your module create a requirejs-config.js file and place it in your module:

```
app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

In the file add the configuration to specify the override:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address':
                'Namespace_Module/template/billing-address'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to drop the `.html` extension from the paths...

Comment: How does it work if the knockoutjs file is in base folder?

Comment: @Black I haven't tested it, but maybe you would create the override in this path: app/code/Namespace/Module/view/base/requirejs-config.js

Comment: @SantiBM, doesnt work either

Comment: If you figured it out, then please answer it here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323215/magento-2-override-knockoutjs-template-located-in-base-folder