# overriding Authentication popup is notworking

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I am very new to magento 2

I have already extended `module_customer` where `authentication-popup.html` is located in that module only, as I want to extend only html file so I used `app\design\frontend\Sm\market\Magento_Checkout` this path but I am not able override it can you help me in this.

Comment: See this thread for an actual solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172504/magento-2-custom-module-override-knockout-template/260695

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Customer/template/authentication-popup.html

Answer (score 0):

you can override below way..

> app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Customer/web/template/authentication-popup.html

Comment: how can I use same pop up in other html file, i mean how to trigger  ?